# ajax array response in loop using display data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, for-loop, foreach

i have pass data to controller and get data in ajax in array so how to use loop in ajax and  display data.

my ajax response is

```
[{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":"0","pay":"\u00a3159.00"},{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":"0","pay":"\u00a3159.00"},{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":0,"pay":"\u00a3159.00"},{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":0,"pay":"\u00a3159.00"}]
```

Comment: i did't see any `multidimensional` array here

Comment: i have pass data in decoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use for...in loop for object with multiple properties and forEach loop for array:

```js
const response = [{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":"0","pay":"\u00a3159.00"},{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":"0","pay":"\u00a3159.00"},{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":0,"pay":"\u00a3159.00"},{"description":"Spring (03\/01\/2017 - 30\/03\/2017) - Training Fees","attandence_count":0,"pay":"\u00a3159.00"}];

response.forEach(session => {
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  for (const key in session) {
       const li = document.createElement("li");
       li.innerHTML= `${key}: ${session[key]}`;
       ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  document.getElementById('session').appendChild(ul);
})
```

```html
<div id="session"></div>
```